# joining multiple regular expression for readability

Tags: python, regex

I have following requirements in date which can be any of the following format.

mm/dd/yyyy or dd Mon YYYY

Few examples are shown below
04/20/2009 and 24 Jan 2001

To handle this I have written regular expression as below

Few text scenarios are metnioned below

> `txt1 = 'Lithium 0.25 (7/11/77).  LFTS wnl.  Urine tox neg.  Serum tox
>   + fluoxetine 500; otherwise neg.  TSH 3.28.  BUN/Cr: 16/0.83.  Lipids unremarkable.  B12 363, Folate >20.  CBC: 4.9/36/308 Pertinent Medical
>   Review of Systems Constitutional:`'
>
> txt2 = "s The patient is a 44 year old married Caucasian woman,
>   unemployed Decorator, living with husband and caring for two young
>   children, who is referred by Capitol Hill Hospital PCP, Dr. Heather
>   Zubia, for urgent evaluation/treatment till first visit with Dr. Toney
>   Winkler IN EIGHT WEEKS on 24 Jan 2001."

```
date = re.findall(r'(?:\b(?<!\.)[\d{0,2}]+)'
                            '(?:[/-]\d{0,}[/-]\d{2,4}) | (?:\b(?<!\.)[\d{1,2}]+)[th|st|nd]*'
                            ' (?:[Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec][a-z]*) \d{2,4}', txtData)
```

I am not getting 24 Jan 2001 where as if I run individually `(?:\b(?<!\.)[\d{1,2}]+)[th|st|nd]* (?:[Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec][a-z]*) \d{2,4}'` I am able to get output.

Question 1: What is bug in above expression?

Question 2: I want to combine both to make more readable as I have to parse any other formats so I used join as shown below

```
RE1 = '(?:\b(?<!\.)[\d{0,2}]+) (?:[/-]\d{0,}[/-]\d{2,4})'
RE2 = '(?:\b(?<!\.)[\d{1,2}]+)[th|st|nd]* (?:[Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec][a-z]*) \d{2,4}'

regex_all = '|'.join([RE1, RE2])
regex_all = re.compile(regex_all)

date = regex_all.findall(txtData) // notice here txtData can be any one of the above string.
```

I am getting output as NaN in case of above for date.

Please suggest what is the mistake if I join.

Thanks for your  help.

Comment: Do not use `[...]` to *group sequences* of chars, use `(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that it is a very bad idea to join such long patterns that also match at the same location within the string. That would cause the regex engine to backtrack too much, and possibly lead to crashes and slowdown. If there is a way to re-write the alternations so that they could only match at different locations, or even get rid of them completely, do it.

Besides, you should use grouping constructs `(...)` to groups sequences of patterns, and only use `[...]` character classes when you need to matches specific chars.

Also, your alternatives are overlapping, you may combine them easily. See the fixed regex:

```
\b(?<!\.)\d{1,2}(?:[/-]\d+[/-]|(?:th|st|[nr]d)?\s*(?:(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*))\s*(?:\d{4}|\d{2})\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kSxCzi/3).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\.)` - no `.` immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing alternation group:

  - `[/-]\d+[/-]` - `/` or `-`, 1+ digits, `-` or `/`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?:th|st|[nr]d)?\s*(?:
    (?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*))` - `th`, `st`, `nd` or `rd` (optionally), followed with 0+ whitespaces, and then month names
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:\d{4}|\d{2})` - 2 or 4 digits
- `\b` - trailing word boundary.

Another note: if you want to match the date-like strings with two matching delimiters, you will need to capture the first one, and use a backreference to match the second one, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WVbdNo/1). In Python, you would need a `re.finditer` to get those matches.

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/muHQ31):

```
import re
rx = r"\b(?<!\.)\d{1,2}(?:([/-])\d+\1|(?:th|st|[nr]d)?\s*(?:(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*))\s*(?:\d{4}|\d{4})\b"
s = "Lithium 0.25 (7/11/77).  LFTS wnl.  Urine tox neg.  Serum tox\nfluoxetine 500; otherwise neg.  TSH 3.28.  BUN/Cr: 16/0.83.  Lipids unremarkable.  B12 363, Folate >20.  CBC: 4.9/36/308 Pertinent Medical\nReview of Systems Constitutional:\n\nThe patient is a 44 year old married Caucasian woman, unemployed Decorator, living with husband and caring for two young children, who is referred by Capitol Hill Hospital PCP, Dr. Heather Zubia, for urgent evaluation/treatment till first visit with Dr. Toney Winkler IN EIGHT WEEKS on 24 Jan 2001"
print([x.group(0) for x in re.finditer(rx, s, re.I)])
# => ['7/11/77', '24 Jan 2001']
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Can you please elaborate how can I use join in python

Comment: @venkysmarty `"|".join(arr_of_values)`? What for? The patterns you tried to join match at the same location inside the string. The resulting pattern would be too slow and you would have too many problems with it.

Comment: But what I didn't understand is that if I run these regegular expressions independently they are working fine. What I am not getting is that if I use | then it stopped working. Though you mentioned that we should not use [ ] instead use ( ) then regular expression should not work for individual expressions also. Am I right. Thanks for answering

Comment: I added some details at the top of my answer. Just do not try to join regexs that way. It is not safe, to say the least. As for `[...]` and `(...)`, you must understand your `[\d{0,2}]+` matches 1 or more digits, `{`, `,` and `}` chars. you clearly wanted to match 0 to 2 digits. Although I can't imagine a case where you want to match 0 digits in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

```
r'(?:\b(?<!\.)[\d{0,2}]+)'
 '(?:[/-]\d{0,}[/-]\d{2,4}) | (?:\b(?<!\.)[\d{1,2}]+)[th|st|nd]*'
 ' (?:[Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec][a-z]*) \d{2,4}'
```

- you should use raw strings (`r'foo'`) for each string, not only the first one. This way backslashes (\) will be considered as normal character and usable by the `re` library.
- `[abc|def]` matches any character between the `[]`, while `(one|two|three)` matches any expression (`one`, `two`, or `three`)

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is too complicated. I suggest using a combination of a simple regex and `strptime()`.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

date_formats = ['%m/%d/%Y', '%d %b %Y']
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(\d\d?/\d\d?/\d{4}|\d\d? \w{3} \d{4})\b')

data = "... your string ..."

for match in re.findall(pattern, data):
    print("Trying to parse '%s'" % match)
    for fmt in date_formats:
        try:
            date = datetime.strptime(match, fmt)
            print(" OK:", date)
            break
        except:
            pass
```

The advantage of this approach is, besides a much more manageable regex, that it won't pick dates that look plausible but do not exist, like `2/29/2000` (whereas `2/29/2004` works).